# Firefox adding some data into simple storage

Tags: sqlite, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I am learning how to make firefox extensions and have gotten totally confused... so I thought I would start from the basics again.

Can you make me  (or walk me through creating) a simple ***skeleton*** extension that saves "ryan" into sqlite storage, so that it is available even on the browser restart?

From there I think I can start modifying it to run all the different code that exists only in my head... and to answer my own questions :))

Thanks!
Ryan

Comment: The Storage page on MDC has examples on most aspects of mozStorage, both in Javascript and C++.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/storage

Answer (score 0):

This is even simpler if you use the [Addon SDK](https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/).

```
var storage = require("simple-storage").storage;
if (storage.name) {
  console.log (storage.name);
}
else {
  console.log ("Storing!");
  storage.name = "ryan";
}
```

This will output "Storing!" the first time it's run, and "ryan" subsequent times.